# Prolog DCGs Multiple Features?

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg

From what I understand, in Prolog you capture features while parsing like so:

```
 foo(feature(X)) --> [X], bar.
```

Is this common when designing DCGs ?

```
 foo(featureA(X), featureB(Y)) --> [X], [Y], bar.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DCGs describe relations between lists and the non-terminals' arguments. However, these arguments are just terms. They can be used to represent features but do not represent them directly. To see the difference, imagine you want to associate a feature numerus to each node. In DCGs you have now to decide, case by case, how to represent that feature. In one node it is `feature(X, singular)` and in another node it might look different. Or you might decide to represent all features uniformly with a list, thus `[nodename=idx,..., numerus=singular,...]`.

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantages of representing them uniformly as a list instead of as a compound(?) term ?

Comment: It is more uniform: So extracting features is much simpler. Putting features into arguments of some compound terms means that you have to write access code for each kind of compound term.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly valid, and quite useful. As an example, consider this rule, taken from the classic (and now free!) book [*PNLA*](http://mtome.com/Publications/PNLA/pnla.html), which uses two arguments to capture the inflection and the "meaning" (the logical form, `LF`) of a transitive verb `tv`:

```
tv(nonfinite,        LF) --> [TV],  {tv(TV, _, _, _, _, LF)}.
tv(finite,           LF) --> [TV],  {tv(_, TV, _, _, _, LF)}.
tv(finite,           LF) --> [TV],  {tv(_, _, TV, _, _, LF)}.
tv(past_participle,  LF) --> [TV],  {tv(_, _, _, TV, _, LF)}.
tv(pres_participle,  LF) --> [TV],  {tv(_, _, _, _, TV, LF)}.
```

A verb can then be defined as

```
tv( write,   writes,   wrote,     written,   writing,    X^Y^ `writes(X,Y)   ).
```

([See full example.](http://mtome.com/Publications/PNLA/PNLA-code/talk.pl))

Comment: Just to point out that lookup by the word form (e.g. 'written') will be slow unless the facts (e.g. `tv/6`) are indexed by all the arguments. A faster lexicon representation would be `tv(written, past_participle, X^Y^writes(X,Y))`.